# C++/ Restricting the instance of class, which other classes are inherit from it

Tags: c++

I want to make a class in C++, which other classes inherit from it. But I want to make sure that no one will be able to make an instance from this class.

Meaning:

```
class Animal{
public:
virtual ~Animal() {}
};

class Fish: public Animal{
};
```

I want to make sure that:

```
Fish* fish = new Fish();
```

would be possible, but

```
Animal* ana = new Animal();
```

would not.

How can I do it?

Comment: Note: `Fish fish;` is also possible, don't go using `new` everywhere ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it an [abstract class](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr142.htm)

Comment: What is an abstract class ? How to make it abstract ? What is the best way *here* ? One liners... are not worth anything.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Unless you've got 78k rep. Then your one liner gets 3 upvotes :)

Comment: Let the OP decide if the answer is worthwhile or not. Let him ask those questions if he needs to.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to make `Animal`'s constructor protected:

```
Class Animal{
protected:
    Animal() {}
public:
    virtual ~Animal() {}
};
```

Since C++ does not provide explicit support for *abstract classes*, but you can add pure virtual functions to your class to get a similar effect. If you do not have a suitable virtual function that you'd want to make pure virtual, a common idiom is to make your destructor pure virtual, and then provide an implementation outside the header.

```
Class Animal{
protected:
    Animal() {}
public:
    virtual ~Animal() = 0;
};

Animal::~Animal() {
    // destructor code
}
```

Comment: 10.4 is a whole section about abstract classes, I would say that its support is pretty explicit, unless explicit just means to have keywords for those things.

Comment: You forgot the copy constructor and there is a slicing issue if you do not also make the assignment operator `protected`. Abstract classes are better.

Comment: @PlasmaHH By "explicit" I mean that there is no way to make a class abstract without adding a pure virtual function - a direct way of communicating the fact that your class is abstract to the compiler, even if you do not need virtual functions, or no functions at all.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I did not forget them - the OP did :) Of course the rule of three still applies.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: It always has a dtor, and you can always make that one pure virtual. You even should make it at least virtual, when you are intending to use a class as a polymorphic base class, which seems to be the prime purpose of abstract base classes.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: note that in your edit, the `protected` constructor is now obsolete. A class having pure functions cannot be instantiated on its own anyway.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I disagree with the idea that polymorphism requires a `virtual` destructor. This is a separate issue. In fact, it is only required for the `delete` on base case which is not as frequent as Java-minded people expect us to believe. That being said, the cost of a `virtual` destructor is so little when one already has other `virtual` methods that it's just simpler to add it from the get go.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I fully agree that C++ has abstract classes covered in all meaningful cases, but conceptually an abstract base class is orthogonal to polymorphic behavior.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Looks like we use quite different design approaches, whenever I work with base classes and interfaces, I work with base class pointers/references only, and when I want to get rid of the object, delete it through that base class pointer (or better said, let a smart pointer do this). I never had a design where the delete was done on a pointer to the actual type.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I did not say there was a `delete` ;) Given `void foo(Base&);`, `Derived d; foo(d);` is a valid use of polymorphism without any kind of dynamic memory allocation. The other typical case is the use of `shared_ptr`, `shared_ptr<Base>(new Derived());` will call `Derived::~Derived` directly (well, via a `delete` this time). As such, I often end up with `protected` destructor in my base classes.

Comment: @MatthieuM. If the reason for inheritance is polymorphism, then you will almost certainly have a `delete` on a pointer to the base class.  Polymorphic classes don't copy (correctly, anyway), so will generally be allocated dynamically.  And of course, the whole point of polymorphism is that you only have pointers and references to the base, once the object has been created.

Comment: @JamesKanze: not necessarily. You are thinking about factories but polymorphism goes far beyond that.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'm not thinking about factories, but the fact that polymorphic objects can't easily have value semantics: unless you're using something like the letter-envelope idiom, they don't support assignment or copy, for example.  And must be accessed through a pointer or a reference.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: As I said, it looks like we use different design approaches, but just because you always use only objects on autostorage or objects in a smart pointer with a deleter that knows about the correct type, doesn't mean the rest of the world does too. As I tried to say, I usually see things deleted through the base pointer a lot. If no one would be deleting through a base pointer, then what sense would the warnings that usual compilers emit for these cases have?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Oh I am well aware of the issue, and I introduced `-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor` in Clang precisely to detect this undefined behavior rather than assuming that all polymorphic classes should have a virtual destructor like the traditional `-Wnon-virtual-dtor`.

Answer (score 2):

The usual idiom for making an abstract class is to have a pure virtual destructor:

```
struct A
{
   A();
   virtual ~A() = 0;
};
```

Note that you'll have to provide an implementation for the destructor, even if it's marked as pure:

```
A::~A()
{
}
```

Comment: In practice, I've never seen a class that needed to be abstract and didn't already have some pure virtual functions.  In which case, you don't need to make the destructor pure virtual (but it should still be virtual).

Comment: @Matthieu M.: It has nothing to do with laziness. You shouldn't assume so much about people's motives and thinking. You seriously think all short answers mean that their providers are lazy? That is an awful bias to have. Did you ever stop and consider other possibilities? Sigh.

Comment: @Jason: [Irony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony). It's not a matter of you being lazy or not, it's just that one-liners do not make good answers. The two inherent short-comings are that they do not provide much to index for (think looking up on Google) and that should the link ever go dead... they do not provide anything. It does not mean links are bad, it means they are useful as a *further* reference but the answer should be able to stand on its own.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: That's such a better and more thoughtful comment than implicitly accusing people of laziness.

Comment: @Jason: I agree, which is why the ironic comment was posted on the answer that could not be accused of laziness *after* a more elaborate comment had been posted on *each* of the one-liner answers. I had thought it would be sufficient to avoid misunderstandings...

Answer (score 0):

The old way is to make the constructor of Animal protected.

The C++11 way is to mark the constructor as deleted.